# matlab display messages

Tags: matlab

sometimes I find that when running matlab scripts messages written through disp() don't show up until the script terminates. Is there a way to force the display of msgs during the script?

Comment: Perhaps SO would be a better place for this question?

Comment: have you tried printf instead?

Comment: What environment? Are you referring to the display of disp() output in the Command Window of the Matlab IDE while you're watching it run, or the text output of a -nodisplay or -nodesktop run, or to a log file created with diary() or -logfile, or something else? They can behave differently; e.g. there's buffering on the log files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html) function. If you're displaying the iteration number in a loop everytime, instead of something like `disp(['Iteration : ', num2str(i)])`, you can simply print the same info as

```
fprintf('Iteration : %u\n',i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `drawnow` call after the `disp()`.

Comment: `drawnow` only affects graphics objects.